# Trying to set up this redux-persist in my store.js file but user not storing anymore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I have implemented redux-persist into my application in order to store the users state post refresh. The issue is now the user isn't storing at all. I suspect it has something to do with how I'm exporting 'store' or how I'm defining the reducers. Either way I'm sure I haven't implemented redux-persist correctly.

Here is my store.js code:

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import persistReducer from "redux-persist/es/persistReducer";
import persistStore from "redux-persist/es/persistStore";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import userReducer from "../Features/userSlice";
import questionReducer from "../Features/questionSlice";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  question: questionReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

let store = createStore(persistedReducer);
let persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

Here is my index.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { store, persistor } from "./app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import { firebaseConfig } from "./firebase";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/lib/integration/react";

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, actually the set up was more or less correct. The issue was that I wasn't able to pick up the state changes in the devtools, which confused me. I made the following changes to the store.js file and it worked:

```
import { combineReducers, createStore, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import persistReducer from "redux-persist/es/persistReducer";
import persistStore from "redux-persist/es/persistStore";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import userReducer from "../Features/userSlice";
import questionReducer from "../Features/questionSlice";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  question: questionReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  );
  let persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persistor };
};
```